# how to get an icons in a dropdownlist

Tags: apache-flex, drop-down-menu

In  a dropdown how to get icons along with text and once we select any of the index from the dropdown i want that icon also be selected and to be displayed on that dropdown header

Answer (score 1):

This article on Peter deHaan's well-known *"Flex Examples"* website should be a good starting point: [Displaying icons in a Flex ComboBox control](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/18/displaying-icons-in-a-flex-combobox-control/).

If you read the comments, you will find the page ["Flex 2.0.1 ComboBox with icon support"](http://flexibleexperiments.wordpress.com/2007/04/28/flex-201-combobox-with-icon-support/), which gives a solution for your question.